# Errors when trying to create a carousel effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I am trying to create a carousel effect for my site but am having issues. My code is as follows but when I try to click on one of the buttons I get an error saying

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: slide is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:22)
```

```js
function slide(dir){
    var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').width();
    if(dir == 'left'){
        var original_indent = $('#carousel_ul').css('left');
        var new_indent = parseInt(original_indent) + item_width;
        $('#carousel_ul').css('left': new_indent);
    }else if(dir == 'right'){
        var original_indent = $('#carousel_ul').css('left');
        var new_indent = parseInt(original_indent) - item_width;
        $('#carousel_ul').css('left': new_indent);
    }
}
```

```css
#carousel_inner{
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#carousel_ul{
    position:relative;
    left:-200px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:9999px;
}
#carousel_ul li{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    padding:0px;
    height:200px;
    background:transparent;
    margin:0px;
}
#left_scroll,#right_scroll{
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    height:150px;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel_container">
    <div id="left_scroll"><button onclick="slide('left');">prev</button></div>
    <div id="carousel_inner">
        <ul id="carousel_ul">
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
            <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="right_scroll"><button onclick="slide('right');">next</button></div>
</div>
```

I was hoping to try get this into an infinite loop as well and was not sure how to go about this.

I was thinking something like:

```
$('#carousel_ul li:first').after($('#carousel_ul li:last'));
$('#carousel_ul li:last').before($('#carousel_ul li:first'));
```

I know there are a load of different pre-made carousels out there but I want to try figure this out myself.

Comment: When you use jQuery's `css()`, you either pass an Object `{ left: new_indent }` or two values `'left', new_indent`. You have the two mixed together. Always check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Hi @ChrisG Thanks for your comment, I tried changing that but am still getting the same error in the console saying that slide() is not defined.

Comment: So there's still another error. Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/hv09dx3q/

Comment: @ChrisG hmmmm strange I just went through that and it was the same tried just copying yours across and it worked. I dunno if it must have been some sort of caching issue or something. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated JS file that includes infinite loop:

```
function slide(dir){
    var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth();
    if(dir == 'left'){
        var original_indent = $('#carousel_ul').css('left');
        var new_indent = parseInt(original_indent) + item_width;
        $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last'));
    }else if(dir == 'right'){
        var original_indent = $('#carousel_ul').css('left');
        var new_indent = parseInt(original_indent) - item_width;
        $('#carousel_ul li:last').after($('#carousel_ul li:first'));
    }
}
```